# How to start Main Window inside Dialog Window Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I made the following panel with QDialog Window:

[image]

I want to, I clicked "OK" button view MainWindow.

I wrote the following code but it did not work

```
void QDialog::pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your QApplication `exec()` is already running, you shold still be able to open a `QMainWindow`, but, in your example, you create the `MainWindow` on the stack inside your functions, and it's scope ends right after the call to `show()`.

This means that the MainWindow object will be freed once the `pushButton_clicked()` function returns.

Tip: Move the declaration of your MainWindow somewhere else, e.g. give it a global scope or move it to the declaration of your own QApplication class, etc.

Comment: You are an example. @Steeve

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to [Steeves answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41119264/7172556) you could also change the code to

```
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow();
    w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    w->show();
```

The allocation on heap will prevent the direct "freeing" and the WA_DeleteOnClose ensures, that the Memeory is freed when you close the Window.

This is a good way if you want a stand-alone Window for which you do not know the Scope.

Comment: Qdialog window running in a Mainwindow. When this code is written in QDialog, QDialog is opening again. It not open Mainwindow. @ab.o2c

Comment: Do you call the Dialog within the Constructor or the show() function of the MainWindow?

Comment: int main (int argc, char *argv) {QApplication a(argc, argv);  QDialog w; w.show(); return a.exec();  } //MainWindow class @ab.o2c